# Lambda filter function not working for two variables

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to multiply each x (from 0-10) with each y (from 0-10) and then only filtering for the ones which in its product are less than 15. However, when I run the code it does not work. I tried filter() and map() but filter() does not seem to work.

It works for when I use map() like this:

```
a=list(map(lambda x,y: x*y<15,range(0,11),range(0,11)))
print (a)
Out:[True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

But when using filter function, it does not like the second range argument for the y. What can I change here?

```
a=list(filter(lambda x,y: x*y<15,range(0,11),range(0,11)))
print (a)
Out:TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

Comment: This is expected behavior. Filter accepts a function, and an iterable. You are providing more arguments than expected. Map allows you to provide multiple iterables, filter does not.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior, while [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) accepts multiple iterables, [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) only accepts one. In order to pass multiple values to a function, pack them into a tuple, and pack multiple iterables to return a tuple using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
a=list(filter(lambda x: x[0]*x[1]<15, zip(range(0,11),range(0,11))))
```

First, we're packing our two iterables into a single iterable returning `(ai, bi)` for iterables `a` and `b`.

```
zip(range(0, 11), range(0, 11))
```

Then, we've changed our anonymous function from accepting two parameters to accepting 1 parameter: a tuple with 2 values:

```
lambda x: x[0]*x[1]<15
```

Which gives us the output:

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks for the clean code and explanation!